# How to write a query for date wise row count of a table in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count

```
Select TO_CHAR("CreatedOn"::DATE,'YYYYMMDD') As ExecutedOn, 
       Count(*) As  Opp 
from "CPR"."Opportunity"
where DATE("CreatedOn")>='2023-01-01' 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("CreatedOn"::DATE,'YYYYMMDD')
Order by Opp;
```

I tried with above query but and getting error as

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP BY TO_CHAR"
> LINE 4: GROUP BY TO_CHAR("CreatedOn"::DATE,'YYYYMMDD')

Can you help me to get the date wise count from last month(2023-01-01) date